# How would I pass variables from a Google Apps Script to an external URL?

Tags: google-apps-script

All I want to do is be able to have a variable like 'rc' that might equal a number, say 37, in my Google Apps Script and then pass that to a URL like https://example.com/proccess.html?rc=37 or something like that.

I can get parameters that I pass into my Google Apps Script easily, but I don't know how to send them to another URL.

Thank you!

Comment: Try [urlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are refering to string manipulation in order to build the URL, you can try the below snippet.

```
 var rc = "37";
 var originalLink = " https://example.com/proccess.html";
 var linkWithParam = originalLink + "?" + "rc" + "=" + rc;
 Logger.log(linkWithParam);
```

If you want to fetch the URL, you can make use of `UrlFetchApp` and use the `fetch(url, params)` method. In this case, the `params` is represented by a JavaScript object specifying the [*advanced parameters*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters).

#### Reference

- [UrlFetchApp Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

Comment: Thank you for your help!